# Symfony 4.4/Doctrine PostgreSQL query with IS NOT TRUE

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am having an issue with the Doctrine Query Builder in my Symfony 4.4 application.

The specific part of my query that is failing is the `IS NOT TRUE` part.

I get the following error:

```
In QueryException.php line 32:
                                                                                     
  [Syntax Error] line 0, col 829: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'IS'
```

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select(
   $qb->expr()->count('s.id').' AS total_clubs',
   "SUM(CASE WHEN s.currentTier = 'platinum' AND s.uefa IS NOT TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS platinum_clubs_non_uefa",
   "SUM(CASE WHEN s.currentTier = 'platinum' AND s.uefa = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS platinum_clubs_uefa",
   "SUM(CASE WHEN s.currentTier = 'gold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS gold_clubs"
)
```

I have a tried a variety of `<> TRUE`, `!= TRUE` and `= FALSE` but I haven't been able to pull the data I want out.

The query that works when I query the PostgreSQL database manually is:

`...AND uefa IS NOT TRUE;`

How can I tweak this query to pull out non-truthy values from this boolean field?

```
composer show | grep doctrine                                                            
doctrine/annotations                 1.13.2             Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       2.1.1              PHP Doctrine Cache library is a popular cache implementation that supports many different drivers...
doctrine/collections                 1.6.8              PHP Doctrine Collections library that adds additional functionality on top of PHP arrays.
doctrine/common                      3.3.0              PHP Doctrine Common project is a library that provides additional functionality that other Doctri...
doctrine/data-fixtures               1.5.3              Data Fixtures for all Doctrine Object Managers
doctrine/dbal                        2.13.8             Powerful PHP database abstraction layer (DBAL) with many features for database schema introspecti...
doctrine/deprecations                v0.5.3             A small layer on top of trigger_error(E_USER_DEPRECATED) or PSR-3 logging with options to disable...
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             2.6.3              Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle    3.4.1              Symfony DoctrineFixturesBundle
doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle  3.0.3              Symfony DoctrineMigrationsBundle
doctrine/event-manager               1.1.1              The Doctrine Event Manager is a simple PHP event system that was built to be used with the variou...
doctrine/inflector                   2.0.4              PHP Doctrine Inflector is a small library that can perform string manipulations with regard to up...
doctrine/instantiator                1.4.1              A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
doctrine/lexer                       1.2.3              PHP Doctrine Lexer parser library that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
doctrine/migrations                  3.4.2              PHP Doctrine Migrations project offer additional functionality on top of the database abstraction...
doctrine/orm                         2.12.1             Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
doctrine/persistence                 2.5.1              The Doctrine Persistence project is a set of shared interfaces and functionality that the differe...
doctrine/sql-formatter               1.1.2              a PHP SQL highlighting library
```

```
pg_config --version
PostgreSQL 12.9
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.9
```

Comment: Why are you using the Entity Manager query builder, and not DBAL's directly `true`/`false` are supported by postgres, but not by DQL since not all DB engines support boolean values.

Comment: @yivi Thanks for the comment. The query has other `where` clauses (not shown). How would you rewrite `SUM(CASE WHEN s.currentTier = 'gold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS gold_clubs` for example?

Comment: Why does it need rewriting?

Comment: @yivi Sorry, i'm not following exactly what you are saying in your comment. What would you suggest doing to pull out false values from that column?

Comment: Looking at that query, I'd say going through DQL instead of a raw SQL query could be a mistake. But if it's not, you need to write DQL, not SQL. And DQL does not understand `TRUE` or `FALSE`, as mentioned earlier. Needs to be something it can be translated to different engines which do not necessarily support booleans. So write `AND s.uefa != :true`, and bind the `:true` parameter to a boolean. `->setParameter('true', true)`.

Comment: @yivi It seems to handle the next line fine and that is using `TRUE` without binding a parameter to `true`, e.g. `SUM(CASE WHEN s.currentTier = 'platinum' AND s.uefa = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS platinum_clubs_uefa`

Comment: Ok, as you wish.

Comment: @yivi So that goes back to my original question of why it allows `= TRUE` but not `IS NOT TRUE`. I've tried it with parameters but it makes no difference. It's the `IS` that's the problem.

Comment: "IS NOT"/"IS" is not supported by DQL, unless for nullable fields. Again, DQL does not natively support boolean fields. The second comparison probably works because a) you are not using "IS TRUE" for comparison, b) it's maybe working by chance by treating "TRUE" as a string or who knows what. The correct way of doing it is the way I explained in may last comment: either use a raw query, or if you must go through DQL, use bound parameters.

Comment: Coincidentally, `IS NULL` works for me in this instance.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment: _"IS"/"IS NOT" is not supported by DQL unless for nullable fields_. Just a few lines up.

Comment: What error do you get when you use `CASE WHEN s.currentTier = 'platinum' AND s.uefa <> true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`? I suspect it has to be different then the one you showed using `IS NOT TRUE`... Should work according to EBNF https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#ebnf

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `IS NOT TRUE`, have you tried `= FALSE`?

Comment: Yes, I said as much in my question: "I have a tried a variety of <> TRUE, != TRUE and = FALSE but I haven't been able to pull the data I want out."